# How do you prevent Rounding off on Distribution > Purchase Requisitions > Requests > Lines > OrderQty?

Tags: acumatica

I've tried all the events still can't do it.
any idea?

Comment: please share events checked by you

Comment: I tried, rowPersisting, rowPersisted, OrderQty_FieldVerifying, OrderQty_FieldUpdating, UOM_FieldUpdating, UOM_FieldVerifying

I mentioned UOM because I saw it in the source code where rounding off occurs. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on Customization->Inspect Element:
[image]

Then click on OrderQty grid column header to identify the DAC field:
[image]

Looking up the code of that field, we see it is decorated with PXDBQuantity attribute:

```
#region OrderQty
public abstract class orderQty : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
protected Decimal? _OrderQty;
[PXDBQuantity(typeof(RQRequestLine.uOM), typeof(RQRequestLine.baseOrderQty), HandleEmptyKey = true)]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Order Qty.", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
[PXFormula(null, typeof(AddCalc<RQRequestLine.openQty>))]
public virtual Decimal? OrderQty
{
    get
    {
        return this._OrderQty;
    }
    set
    {
        this._OrderQty = value;
    }
}
#endregion
```

PXDBQuantity attribute derives from PXDBDecimalAttribute, rounding happens in PXDBDecimalAttribute:

```
public class PXDBQuantityAttribute : PXDBDecimalAttribute, IPXFieldVerifyingSubscriber, IPXRowInsertingSubscriber
```

To modify the rounding logic you could create your own PXDBQuantity attribute and make it inherit from your own PXDBDecimal attribute with custom truncating logic instead of rounding. Then you can override the OrderQty PXDBQuantity attribute with your own attribute:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.PO;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.AP;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using System.Collections;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.TM;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.RQ;
using System.Threading;

namespace PX.Objects.RQ
{
  
  public class RQRequestEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<RQRequestEntry>
  {
    // Redefine OrderQty attributes, replace PXDBQuantity attribute by 
    // your own PXDBQuantityNoRounding attribute which herits from
    // PXDBDecimalNoRounding instead PXDBDecimal.
    // Replace Math.Round calls in PXDBDecimalNoRounding by your own truncating logic
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Replace)]
    [PXDBQuantityNoRounding(typeof(RQRequestLine.uOM), typeof(RQRequestLine.baseOrderQty), HandleEmptyKey = true)]
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Order Qty.", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
    [PXFormula(null, typeof(AddCalc<RQRequestLine.openQty>))]
    public virtual void RQRequestLine_OrderQty_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
    {
    }
  }

  #region PXDBQuantityAttribute

  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Class)]
  public class PXDBQuantityNoRoundingAttribute : PXDBDecimalNoRoundingAttribute, IPXFieldVerifyingSubscriber, IPXRowInsertingSubscriber
  {
    #region State
    protected int _ResultOrdinal;
    protected int _KeyOrdinal;
    protected Type _KeyField = null;
    protected Type _ResultField = null;
    protected bool _HandleEmptyKey = false;
    protected int? _OverridePrecision = null;

    public Type KeyField
    {
      get
      {
        return _KeyField;
      }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Ctor
    public PXDBQuantityNoRoundingAttribute()
    {
    }

    public PXDBQuantityNoRoundingAttribute(Type keyField, Type resultField)
    {
      _KeyField = keyField;
      _ResultField = resultField;
    }

    public PXDBQuantityNoRoundingAttribute(int precision, Type keyField, Type resultField)
    {
      _OverridePrecision = precision;
      _KeyField = keyField;
      _ResultField = resultField;
    }

    public bool HandleEmptyKey
    {
      set { this._HandleEmptyKey = value; }
      get { return this._HandleEmptyKey; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Runtime
    public override void CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
    {
      base.CacheAttached(sender);

      _Precision = CommonSetupDecPl.Qty;

      if (_OverridePrecision != null)
        _Precision = _OverridePrecision.Value;

      if (_ResultField != null)
      {
        _ResultOrdinal = sender.GetFieldOrdinal(_ResultField.Name);
      }

      if (_KeyField != null)
      {
        _KeyOrdinal = sender.GetFieldOrdinal(_KeyField.Name);
        sender.Graph.FieldUpdated.AddHandler(BqlCommand.GetItemType(_KeyField), _KeyField.Name, KeyFieldUpdated);
      }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Implementation
    internal virtual object Select(PXCache cache, object data)
    {
      foreach (PXEventSubscriberAttribute attr in cache.GetAttributes(data, _KeyField.Name))
      {
        if (attr is INUnitAttribute)
        {
          object value = cache.GetValue(data, _KeyField.Name);
          return PXSelectorAttribute.GetItem(cache, (PXSelectorAttribute)((INUnitAttribute)attr).SelectorAttr, data, value);
        }
      }
      return null;
    }

    protected virtual void CalcBaseQty(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
    {
      decimal? resultval = null;

      if (_ResultField != null)
      {
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
          bool handled = false;
          if (this._HandleEmptyKey)
          {
            object value = sender.GetValue(e.Row, _KeyField.Name);
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((String)value))
            {
              resultval = (decimal)e.NewValue;
              handled = true;
            }
          }
          if (!handled)
          {
            if ((decimal)e.NewValue == 0)
            {
              resultval = 0m;
            }
            else
            {
            INUnit conv = (INUnit)Select(sender, e.Row);

            if (conv != null && conv.UnitRate != 0m)
            {
              _ensurePrecision(sender, e.Row);

                decimal? resultFieldCurrentValue = (decimal?)sender.GetValue(e.Row, this._ResultField.Name);
                bool reverseConvEqual = false;
                if (resultFieldCurrentValue != null)
                {
                  decimal revValue = Math.Round((resultFieldCurrentValue ?? 0m) * (conv.UnitMultDiv == "M" ? 1 / (decimal)conv.UnitRate : (decimal)conv.UnitRate), (int)_Precision, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
                  if (revValue == (decimal)e.NewValue)
                    reverseConvEqual = true;
                }

                if (reverseConvEqual)
                  resultval = resultFieldCurrentValue;
                else
              resultval = Math.Round((decimal)e.NewValue * (conv.UnitMultDiv == "M" ? (decimal)conv.UnitRate : 1 / (decimal)conv.UnitRate), (int)_Precision, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            }

            if (conv == null && !e.ExternalCall)
            {
              throw new PXUnitConversionException((string)sender.GetValue(e.Row, _KeyField.Name)); 
            }
          }
        }
        }
        if (e.ExternalCall)
        {
          sender.SetValueExt(e.Row, this._ResultField.Name, resultval);
        }
        else
        {
          sender.SetValue(e.Row, this._ResultField.Name, resultval);
        }
      }
    }

    protected virtual void CalcBaseQty(PXCache sender, object data)
    {
      object NewValue = sender.GetValue(data, _FieldOrdinal);
      try
      {
        CalcBaseQty(sender, new PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs(data, NewValue, false));
      }
      catch (PXUnitConversionException)
      {
        sender.SetValue(data, _ResultField.Name, null);
      }
    }

    protected virtual void CalcTranQty(PXCache sender, object data)
    {
      decimal? resultval = null;

      if (_ResultField != null)
      {
        object NewValue = sender.GetValue(data, _ResultOrdinal);

        if (NewValue != null)
        {
          INUnit conv = (INUnit)Select(sender, data);

          if (conv != null && conv.UnitRate != 0m)
          {
            _ensurePrecision(sender, data);
            resultval = Math.Round((decimal)NewValue * (conv.UnitMultDiv == "M" ? 1 / (decimal)conv.UnitRate : (decimal)conv.UnitRate), (int)_Precision, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
          }
        }
        sender.SetValue(data, _FieldOrdinal, resultval);
      }
    }

    public static void CalcBaseQty<TField>(PXCache cache, object data)
      where TField : class, IBqlField
    {
      foreach (PXEventSubscriberAttribute attr in cache.GetAttributes<TField>(data))
      {
        if (attr is PXDBQuantityNoRoundingAttribute)
        {
          ((PXDBQuantityNoRoundingAttribute)attr).CalcBaseQty(cache, data);
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    public static void CalcTranQty<TField>(PXCache cache, object data)
      where TField : class, IBqlField
    {
      foreach (PXEventSubscriberAttribute attr in cache.GetAttributes<TField>(data))
      {
        if (attr is PXDBQuantityNoRoundingAttribute)
        {
          ((PXDBQuantityNoRoundingAttribute)attr).CalcTranQty(cache, data);
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    public static decimal Round(decimal? value)
    {
      decimal value0 = value ?? 0m;
      return Math.Round(value0, CommonSetupDecPl.Qty, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }

    public virtual void KeyFieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
      CalcBaseQty(sender, e.Row);
    }

    public override void RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
    {
            if ((e.Operation & PXDBOperation.Command) == PXDBOperation.Delete) return;
      object NewValue = sender.GetValue(e.Row, _FieldOrdinal);
      CalcBaseQty(sender, new PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs(e.Row, NewValue, false));
    }

    public virtual void RowInserting(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertingEventArgs e)
    {
      CalcBaseQty(sender, e.Row);
    }

    public virtual void FieldVerifying(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
    {
      PXFieldUpdatingEventArgs args = new PXFieldUpdatingEventArgs(e.Row, e.NewValue);
      if (!e.ExternalCall)
      {
        base.FieldUpdating(sender, args);
      }
      CalcBaseQty(sender, new PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs(args.Row, args.NewValue, true));
      e.NewValue = args.NewValue;
    }
    #endregion
  }

  #endregion

  #region PXDBDecimalAttribute
    /// <summary>Maps a DAC field of <tt>decimal?</tt> type to the database
    /// column of <tt>decimal</tt> type.</summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <para>The attribute is added to the value declaration of a DAC field.
    /// The field becomes bound to the database column with the same
    /// name.</para>
    /// <para>A minimum value, maximum value, and precision can be specified.
    /// The precision can be calculated at runtime using BQL. The default
    /// precision is 2.</para>
    /// </remarks>
    /// <example>
    /// Declaration of a DAC field with a specific precision is shown below.
    /// <code>
    /// [PXDBDecimal(6, MinValue = 0, MaxValue = 100)]
    /// public virtual decimal? Price { get; set; }</code>
    /// </example>
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
  public class PXDBDecimalNoRoundingAttribute : PXDBFieldAttribute, IPXRowSelectingSubscriber, IPXCommandPreparingSubscriber, IPXFieldUpdatingSubscriber, IPXFieldSelectingSubscriber, IPXRowPersistingSubscriber
  {
    #region State

    public class DBDecimalProperties
    {
      public int? _scale;
      public int? _precision;
      public decimal? _maxValue;

      public int? Scale
      {
        get
        {
          _sync.AcquireReaderLock(-1);
          try {
            return _scale;
          }
          finally {
            _sync.ReleaseReaderLock();
          }
        }
      }

      public int? Precision
      {
        get
        {
          _sync.AcquireReaderLock(-1);
          try {
            return _precision;
          }
          finally {
            _sync.ReleaseReaderLock();
          }
        }
      }

      public decimal? MaxValue
      {
        get
        {
          _sync.AcquireReaderLock(-1);
          try {
            return _maxValue;
          }
          finally {
            _sync.ReleaseReaderLock();
          }
        }
      }


      private ReaderWriterLock _sync = new ReaderWriterLock();

      public void Fill(Type table, string field)
      {
        _sync.AcquireReaderLock(-1);
        try {
          if (_scale != null && _precision != null && _maxValue != null)
            return;

          var lc = _sync.UpgradeToWriterLock(-1);
          try
          {
            if (_scale != null && _precision != null && _maxValue != null)
              return;

            var tableHeader = PXDatabase.Provider.GetTableStructure(table.Name);
            if (tableHeader != null)
            {
              var column = tableHeader
                .Columns.FirstOrDefault(c => string.Equals(c.Name, field, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
              if (column != null)
              {
                _scale = column.Scale;
                _precision = column.Precision;
                _maxValue = (decimal?)Math.Pow(10, (double)(column.Precision - column.Scale));
              }
              else
              {
                _scale = 29;
                _precision = 28;
                _maxValue = decimal.MaxValue;
              }
            }
          }
          catch
          {
          }
          finally
          {
            _sync.DowngradeFromWriterLock(ref lc);
          }
        }
        finally {
          _sync.ReleaseReaderLock();
        }
      }

      public bool IsSet
      {
        get
        {
          _sync.AcquireReaderLock(-1);
          try {
            return _scale != null && _precision != null && _maxValue != null;
          }
          finally {
            _sync.ReleaseReaderLock();
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // because attributes instantiating by copying there will be only one instance for all instances of field.
        /// <exclude/>
    public DBDecimalProperties DBProperties { get; private set; }

    protected int? _Precision = 2;
    protected decimal _MinValue = decimal.MinValue;
    protected decimal _MaxValue = decimal.MaxValue;
    protected Type _Type;
    protected BqlCommand _Select;
        /// <summary>Gets or sets the minimum value for the field.</summary>
    public double MinValue
    {
      get
      {
        return (double)_MinValue;
      }
      set
      {
        _MinValue = (decimal)value;
      }
    }
        /// <summary>Gets or sets the minimum value for the field.</summary>
    public double MaxValue
    {
      get
      {
        return (double)_MaxValue;
      }
      set
      {
        _MaxValue = (decimal)value;
      }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Ctor
        /// <summary>Initializes a new instance with the default precision, which
        /// equals 2.</summary>
        /// <example>
        /// <code>
        /// [PXDBDecimal(MaxValue = 100, MinValue = 0)]
        /// [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "50.0")]
        /// [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Group/Document Discount Limit (%)")]
        /// public virtual Decimal? DiscountLimit { get; set; }
        /// </code>
        /// </example>
    public PXDBDecimalNoRoundingAttribute()
    {
      DBProperties = new DBDecimalProperties();
    }
        /// <summary>Initializes a new instance with the given
        /// precision.</summary>
        /// <example>
        /// <code>
        /// [PXDBDecimal(4)]
        /// [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
        /// public virtual Decimal? TaxTotal { get; set; }
        /// </code>
        /// </example>
    public PXDBDecimalNoRoundingAttribute(int precision)
      : this()
    {
      _Precision = precision;
    }

        /// <summary>Initializes a new instance with the precision calculated at
        /// runtime using a BQL query.</summary>
        /// <param name="type">A BQL query based on a class derived from
        /// <tt>IBqlSearch</tt> or <tt>IBqlField</tt>. For example, the parameter
        /// can be set to <tt>typeof(Search&lt;...&gt;)</tt>, or
        /// <tt>typeof(Table1.field)</tt>.</param>
        /// <example>
        /// The code below shows declaration of a DAC field with a precision calculated
        /// at runtime. The BQL query in this example will search for the <tt>Currency</tt> data record
        /// that satisfies the specified <tt>Where</tt> condition. The field precision will be
        /// set to the <tt>DecimalPlaces</tt> value from this data record.
        /// <code>
        /// [PXDBDecimal(typeof(
        ///     Search&lt;Currency.decimalPlaces,
        ///         Where&lt;Currency.curyID, Equal&lt;Current&lt;POCreateFilter.vendorID&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;
        /// ))]
        /// public virtual decimal? OrderTotal { get; set; }
        /// </code>
        /// </example>
    public PXDBDecimalNoRoundingAttribute(Type type)
      : this()
    {
      if (type == null) {
        throw new PXArgumentException(type.Name, ErrorMessages.ArgumentNullException);
      }
      if (typeof(IBqlSearch).IsAssignableFrom(type)) {
        _Select = BqlCommand.CreateInstance(type);
        _Type = BqlCommand.GetItemType(((IBqlSearch)_Select).GetField());
      }
      else if (type.IsNested && typeof(IBqlField).IsAssignableFrom(type)) {
        _Type = BqlCommand.GetItemType(type);
        _Select = BqlCommand.CreateInstance(typeof(Search<>), type);
      }
      else {
        throw new PXArgumentException(type.Name, ErrorMessages.CantCreateForeignKeyReference, type);
      }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Runtime

        /// <summary>Sets the precision in the attribute instance that marks the
        /// field with the specified name in a particular data record.</summary>
        /// <param name="cache">The cache object to search for the attributes of
        /// <tt>PXDBDecimal</tt> type.</param>
        /// <param name="data">The data record the method is applied to.</param>
        /// <param name="name">The name of the field that is be marked with the
        /// attribute.</param>
        /// <param name="precision">The new precision value.</param>
        /// <example>
        /// The code below shows the <tt>RowSelected</tt> event handler (used to
        /// configure the UI at run time), in which you set the precision for the
        /// <tt>Qty</tt> field in the provided data record.
        /// <code>
        /// protected virtual void LotSerOptions_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        /// {
        ///     LotSerOptions opt = (LotSerOptions)e.Row;
        ///     ...
        ///     PXDBDecimalAttribute.SetPrecision(sender, opt, "Qty", (opt.IsSerial == true ? 0 : INSetupDecPl.Qty));
        ///     ...
        /// }
        /// </code>
        /// </example>
    public static void SetPrecision(PXCache cache, object data, string name, int? precision)
    {
      if (data == null) {
        cache.SetAltered(name, true);
      }
      foreach (PXEventSubscriberAttribute attr in cache.GetAttributes(data, name)) {
        if (attr is PXDBDecimalNoRoundingAttribute) {
          ((PXDBDecimalNoRoundingAttribute)attr)._Precision = precision;
        }
      }
    }
        /// <summary>Sets the precision in the attribute instance that marks the
        /// field with the specified name in all data records in the cache
        /// object.</summary>
        /// <param name="cache">The cache object to search for the attributes of
        /// <tt>PXDBDecimal</tt> type.</param>
        /// <param name="name">The name of the field that is be marked with the
        /// attribute.</param>
        /// <param name="precision">The new precision value.</param>
    public static void SetPrecision(PXCache cache, string name, int? precision)
    {
      cache.SetAltered(name, true);
      foreach (PXEventSubscriberAttribute attr in cache.GetAttributes(name)) {
        if (attr is PXDBDecimalNoRoundingAttribute) {
          ((PXDBDecimalNoRoundingAttribute)attr)._Precision = precision;
        }
      }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Implementation

    protected string Check(object value)
    {
      if (value is decimal) {
        decimal val = Normalize((decimal)value);

        if (!DBProperties.IsSet) {
          DBProperties.Fill(_BqlTable, _DatabaseFieldName);
        }
        // if can`t read properties - ignoring check.
        if (DBProperties.IsSet) {
          if (Math.Abs(val) >= DBProperties.MaxValue) {
            return PXMessages.LocalizeFormat(ErrorMessages.InvalidDecimalValue, _FieldName);
          }
        }
      }

      return null;
    }

    protected decimal Normalize(decimal value)
    {
      return decimal.Round(value, 28);
    }

        /// <exclude/>
    public virtual void RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
    {
      object val = sender.GetValue(e.Row, _FieldOrdinal);
      string error = Check(val);
      if (error != null) {
        if (sender.RaiseExceptionHandling(_FieldName, e.Row, null, new PXSetPropertyKeepPreviousException(error))) {
          throw new PXRowPersistingException(_FieldName, null, error);
        }
      }
    }

        /// <exclude/>
    protected override void PrepareCommandImpl(string dbFieldName, PXCommandPreparingEventArgs e)
    {
      base.PrepareCommandImpl(dbFieldName, e);
      e.DataType = PXDbType.Decimal;
      e.DataLength = 16;
    }

        /// <exclude/>
    public override void RowSelecting(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Row != null) {
        sender.SetValue(e.Row, _FieldOrdinal, e.Record.GetDecimal(e.Position));
      }
      e.Position++;
    }
        /// <exclude/>
    public virtual void FieldUpdating(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatingEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.NewValue is string) {
        decimal val;
        if (decimal.TryParse((string)e.NewValue, NumberStyles.Any, sender.Graph.Culture, out val)) {
          e.NewValue = val;
        }
        else {
          e.NewValue = null;
        }
      }
      if (e.NewValue != null) {
        _ensurePrecision(sender, e.Row);
        if (_Precision != null) {
          e.NewValue = Math.Round((decimal)e.NewValue, (int)_Precision, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        }
        string error = Check(e.NewValue);
        if (error != null) {
          throw new PXSetPropertyException(error);
        }
      }
    }
        /// <exclude/>
    public virtual void FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
      if (_AttributeLevel == PXAttributeLevel.Item || e.IsAltered) {
        _ensurePrecision(sender, e.Row);
        e.ReturnState = PXDecimalState.CreateInstance(e.ReturnState, _Precision, _FieldName, _IsKey, -1, _MinValue, _MaxValue);
      }
    }
    protected void _ensurePrecision(PXCache sender, object row)
    {
      if (_Type != null) {
        PXView view = sender.Graph.TypedViews.GetView(_Select, true);
        object item = null;
        try {
          List<object> list = view.SelectMultiBound(new object[] { row });
          if (list.Count > 0) item = list[0];
        }
        catch {
        }
        if (item != null) {
          int? prec = GetItemPrecision(view, item);
          if (prec != null)
            _Precision = prec;
        }
      }
    }

        /// <summary>Retrieves the precision value if it is set by a BQL query
        /// specified in the constructor, and sets its to all attribute instances
        /// in the cache object.</summary>
        /// <param name="cache">The cache object to search for the attributes of
        /// <tt>PXDBDecimal</tt> type.</param>
    public static void EnsurePrecision(PXCache cache)
    {
      foreach (PXEventSubscriberAttribute attr in cache.GetAttributesReadonly(null)) {
        PXDBDecimalNoRoundingAttribute decattr = attr as PXDBDecimalNoRoundingAttribute;
        if (decattr != null && decattr.AttributeLevel == PXAttributeLevel.Cache) {
          int? oldValue = decattr._Precision;
          try {
            decattr._Precision = null;
            decattr._ensurePrecision(cache, null);
            oldValue = (int)decattr._Precision;

            cache.SetAltered(decattr._FieldName, true);
            decattr._Type = null;
          }
          catch (InvalidOperationException) { }
          finally {
            decattr._Precision = oldValue;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    #endregion

    protected virtual int? GetItemPrecision(PXView view, object item)
    {
      if (item is PXResult) item = ((PXResult)item)[0];
      return item != null ? (short?)view.Cache.GetValue(item, ((IBqlSearch)_Select).GetField().Name) : null;
    }

  }

  #endregion
}
```

Comment: I assumed that 'prevent rounding off' means truncate instead of rounding. If what you really want is instead to change the number of decimal used for calculations you'll want to look into modifying Precision instead of Math.Round.